# Set Allowed Countries on Store View

Tags: magento2, online-store

In Magento 1.4, I was able to set `allowed countries` on the `Store View` Level, therefore I could have a `Website` with one `Store` und multiple `Store Views` for each of my countries:
[image]

Now in Magento 2, I can only set the `Allowed Countries` on the `Website` and not on the `Store View`, the `Store View` setting looks as follows:
[image]

Why do I want to change that? I need to be able to set a different `store contact address` for each of these `Store View`s, because I e.g. have an Argentinien und a Bulgarian `Store View`, so I want to set the different addresses but use the same `Website`/`Store`.

Unfortunately, I'm also not able to change the `Store Contact Address` per `Store View` anymore, this also only works on `Website` Level.

Am I missing something? Was there a logical change from 1.X to 2.X about the `Store Views`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the allowed country option was removed from settings in store view. But looking in the code shows that the information is used if present. So you can just enter the data into core_config_data (scope: stores, scope_id: your_store_id, value: AT,AB,AC...

Answer (score 3):

the correct answer that respects Magento 2 standardization is overloading the system.xml of the magento/Backend/etc/adminhtml.
 you should try:
Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="general">
            <group id="country" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Country Options</label>
                <field id="allow" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Allow Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Remember to add overridden module - Magento_Backend

Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```